# How to avoid repeating "a.condition_A==b.condition_A" in if statements about "compare condition A first, if equals, then B, then C..."?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For example, there is a piece of code to find the best student according to their exam results, with maths result first, if having the same maths score, then use en result and then es result:

```js
const students=[
  {"name":"Ada","maths":58,"en":70,"es":60},
  {"name":"Bob","maths":70,"en":54,"es":42},
  {"name":"Tom","maths":60,"en":50,"es":50}
];
let bestIndex=0;
let bestMaths=0;
let bestEn=0;
let bestEs=0;
let index=0;
for(const s of students){
  if(s.maths>bestMaths || 
    (s.maths==bestMaths && s.en>bestEn) ||
    (s.maths==bestMaths && s.en==bestEn && s.es>bestEs)){
    bestIndex=index;
    bestMaths=s.maths;
    bestEn=s.en;
    bestEs=s.es
  }
  index++
}
document.write(bestIndex);
```

While the code works fines currently, the coding style is not good looking because it is repeating

```
s.maths==bestMaths
```

. Also when adding a new requirement : "select student with highest score in all language subjects before comparing en result", new "a==b" statements is required to repeat (repeating "s.en+s.es==bestTotalLang" at the following):

```
 s.maths>bestMaths || 
(s.maths==bestMaths && s.en+s.es>bestTotalLang) ||
(s.maths==bestMaths && s.en+s.es==bestTotalLang && s.en>bestEn) ||
(s.maths==bestMaths && s.en+s.es==bestTotalLang && s.en==bestEn && s.es>bestEs)
```

Also it is required to rewrite the "pyramid" of code above when the priority of condition changed, for example : select student with best en first, then maths and then es.

My question is, is there any coding style to rewrite the code above, which can avoid repeating s.maths==bestMaths (ie: allow "s.maths==bestMaths" appears once only), and also for other "a==b" statements?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Answer (score 2):

For the general case of a repetitive comparison, as long as impure getters aren't involved, you can store the compare result in a variable and then use that variable. So

```
s.maths>bestMaths || 
(s.maths==bestMaths && ...
(s.maths==bestMaths && ...
(s.maths==bestMaths && ...
```

could become

```
const thisBest = s.maths==bestMaths;
s.maths>bestMaths || 
(thisBest && ...
(thisBest && ...
(thisBest && ...
```

But for this particular logic you're going with, it would be easier to perform the `s.maths==bestMaths` check first, once, in a single branch, then list out into the other possibilities in a big `&&` that follows.

```js
const students=[{"name":"Ada","maths":58,"en":70,"es":60},{"name":"Bob","maths":70,"en":54,"es":42},{"name":"Tom","maths":60,"en":50,"es":50}];
let bestIndex=0;
let bestMaths=0;
let bestEn=0;
let bestEs=0;
let index=0;
for (const s of students) {
  if (s.maths > bestMaths || (s.maths == bestMaths && (
    s.en > bestEn
    || (s.en == bestEn && s.es > bestEs)
    // add other conditions here
  ))) {
    bestIndex = index;
    bestMaths = s.maths;
    bestEn = s.en;
    bestEs = s.es
  }
  index++
}
console.log(bestIndex);
```

A better way to approach this would be to `.reduce` while keeping the best student so far in the accumulator, then log its index at the end.

```js
const students=[{"name":"Ada","maths":58,"en":70,"es":60},{"name":"Bob","maths":70,"en":54,"es":42},{"name":"Tom","maths":60,"en":50,"es":50}];
const bestStudent = students.reduce((a, s) => (
  (
    s.maths > a.maths ||
    (s.maths === a.maths && s.en > a.en) ||
    (s.maths === a.maths && s.en === a.en && s.es > a.es)
  ) ? s : a
));
const bestIndex = students.indexOf(bestStudent);
console.log(bestIndex);
```

It may be a bit repetitive, but repetitiveness is not always the enemy *in itself* - it's OK to be somewhat repetitive if the alternative is sacrificing readability.

Answer (score 0):

A readable solution can be achieved without repetitions. Here is my take on it:

```js
const students=[{"name":"Ada","maths":58,"en":70,"es":60},{"name":"Bob","maths":70,"en":54,"es":42},{"name":"Tom","maths":60,"en":50,"es":50},{"name":"Mary","maths":70,"en":53,"es":65}];

const best=students.reduce((a,c)=>
  c.maths>a.maths
   ?c
   :c.maths==a.maths
    ?c.en>a.en
     ?c
     :c.en==a.en&&c.es>a.es
      ?c
      :a
    :a );

console.log(best);
console.log(students.indexOf(best))
```

Comment: Ternary operators are generally considered _not_ readable. Nesting 10 of them is _definitely_ not considered readable.